# How can I improve the file size of my generated GIF?

Tags: java, android, encoding, gif

I'm trying to add GIF generation functionality to my app so that the user can share their animated creations with their friends, etc.

In my app, the user can pick a static background image to have a item drop down onto, so the only moving part is the item.

I have the GIF generation [working fine using this encoder](http://pastebin.com/2J5V3sGj) which is based on [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/AnimatedGifEncoder.htm), and the finished product looks the way I want it, but if the user chooses to have a background image, the file size goes over my target size of 3MB. [Here is an example.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3373854/DWI_023.gif)

I also assume any tablet users would get huge files as well since the image size is the size of the view it's generated from. All the GIFS are around 12-20 frames, so I'm guessing the issue is the number of colors, or that the colors of the background image are changing slightly from frame to frame for some reason.

---

So is there any way I can get the filesize consistently below 3MB, while maintaining the FPS and dimensions? (Altering the GIF generation code/Changing the colors of the background image/etc) Or if not, what would be the best way to get it below 3MB and still attract users?

Thanks in advance! (:

**EDIT:**
It looks like the problem is that the class I'm using doesn't optimize each frame as a diff or delta of the last. Any suggestions? (:

Comment: Did you inspect the image with an appropriate tool, that can show you the actual frame contents? They should only contain the delta to the previous frame. Oh, and how big is the file when you do just a single frame animation? That is a good control, too. If the problem arises with a single frame already, it's the background image you chose. GIF isn't meant for Photos.

Comment: What would an "appropriate tool" be to check it out?

Comment: Any tool that can disassemble Gif animations. For example GIMP. Inspect the individual layers.

Comment: [The first frame](http://i.imgur.com/Tma1D.gif) is 108kb. And I'll inspect it in GIMP now.

Comment: Okay so it looks like that class that I'm using doesnt do any diff/delta-ing of the frames since each frame/layer is the full image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that only the first frame contains the full image. Subsequent frames should only contain the **differences to the previous frame**. This should turn a large part of the frame transparent, which can be compressed much more efficiently by GIF.
Do the following test: if you double the framerate - does the file size double? If so, you currently don't encode deltas only.

Also understand that GIF isn't appropriate for photos, and will produce huge files or a really bad image quality.

**Edit**: So you might need to improve your image-generating code so that it only feeds the changed parts of the image to the encoder!

Comment: I opened the gif up in GIMP and it looks like each frame is a full image, so it looks like that is the problem.

And yeah, I understand the quality implications of having GIFs, but since the background image is static, it _looks_ good enough at the moment.

Comment: Well, 108k for the first frame propbably is acceptable enough. It probably still wastes quite some bandwidth, but unless you are serving this image on "cloud scale" you don't need to bother, modern internet lines are fast (I still remember the time when a webpage with all images was supposed to be less than 30k to load sensibly with modems!)

Comment: Well my goal is too keep it under 3MB so it can be uploaded to Imgur by the user. If I was just letting them share it via e-mail/sms it would be fine.

I need to see if anyone can point me to a way to add the delta functionality to my encoder.

Comment: How about adding it yourself? Just compare what parts of the image have changed, set the others to transparent!

Comment: I think it's a bit over my head with the neural-net quantization, and optimization. Any thing I made myself, even if it worked, would probably take an hour to run (versus the 3s/frame rendering time now)

Comment: Don't change the encoder. Change the data *before* you encode it to GIF!